# How can I access google sheet data(it's shared with me ,only read access) via a node app

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I have a google sheet shared with me to which I have just the view access.The access is shared to me via my google account .I want to create a node app which basically can fetch the data,so I can create a rest api around it which I want to use with my frontend.

It looks like I need APIs keys to fetch the data.How to obtain those keys,given my account just have view access

Comment: Ask someone with higher access to provide the API keys.

Comment: the API keys are not related to a particular Google Sheet, but to your GCP account.  See [here](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158862?hl=en) how to create an API key.

Answer (score 2):

To access a sheet shared by another user from within a Node.js app you can use **Service Accounts**. This will work if the user granting access to you would also support granting the access to said Service Account. Create a Service Account within the [credentials section](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis) of your Google API account. Service Accounts are created with a generated email address. Ask the sheet owner to share the sheet with this email address (e.g. for read-only access). Be also sure to save the service account's key to a JSON file that can be loaded by a Google API client library.

If you want to learn more about the details of the Auth-Flow, check out the [Google OAuth2.0 guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account), especially the HTTP/REST section in [Preparing to make an authorized API call](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests).

The easy way to use this in Node.js is with [Google APIs Node.js Client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client). The section on service account credentials tells you how to [authenticate using the key file](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#service-account-credentials).

Find below a copy of the code listed there showing how to specify the key file and specifying the scope for using to spreadsheet.read-only.

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');

const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
  keyFile: '/path/to/your-secret-key.json',
  scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']
});
```

The resulting `auth` object can be used to make the call to the Sheets API. For details, check the [samples provided by google](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/samples/sheets/quickstart.js). Just use the `auth` object as built above.